# Monitoring and restarting background processes in Emacs

Tags: email, timers

I have a background process to sync and index email. The two function calls in there, `(mail-sync)` and `(mail-index)` are calls with `start-process`. I then run the `mail-background` function periodically with `run-with-timer`.

The relevant code is:

```
(defun mail-background ()
  (set-process-sentinel
    (mail-sync)
    (lambda (p e)
      (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
        (mail-index)))))

(run-with-timer 0 (* 5 60) 'mail-background)
```

There are two issues I have with this setup:

1. I don't know how to monitor the timer, so I can see failures, when it stopped running, etc.
2. When my computer (macOS) goes to sleep, sometimes the timer continues when I come back, and sometimes it has stopped, which brings me to the first point.

I'm sure there is a better way to do what I am doing, so any pointer on that appreciated. Or, I'd just like to know how I can monitor and restart the background processes that are being run with `run-with-timer` as a first step.

Comment: Why does your background process have to be running all the time?  If you create a simple recurring timer function that displays a message of "hello-world", are you able to see it resume when your computer wakes up after a long-sleep?  How about just running a *new* process each time your computer runs the timer function, which can also be on an idle-timer so as not to interrupt your workflow?  [I don't use `mu4e` specifically because it has a background `mu` process running 24/7 and I refused to subject myself to that type of abuse ... :)]

Comment: In addition to the previous comment about avoiding the dilemma of a killed process, you may be interested in `get-process` to test for a running process:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Process-Information.html  If it does not exist, then start a new one.